# How is browser localStorage read-only?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, local-storage

These two ([one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [two](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)) resources state that localStorage is read-only, but localStorage can be written to with `localStorage.set("key", "value")`. What does read-only mean in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What they mean by read-only is that the property "localStorage" or "window.localStorage" or "self.localStorage" can't be written to or reassigned.   It will always be "Storage"

If you try to do...

```
localStorage = undefined;
```

(or try to assign anything to localStorage)

localStorage will be unchanged and still be localStorage.   It can also be said that the localStorage property is immutable.